# Show list of categories even if they have no posts

Tags: categories

Is there a way to show a list of all categories available even if there are no posts associated with them. So if there is a post in that category then it echos a link and if not it just echos out the name of the category?

I'm using wp_list_categories() to show them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an argument called `hide_empty` which is true by default.

```
$args = array('hide_empty' => FALSE);
wp_list_categories($args);
```

Codex: [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Answer (score 1):

Actually `hide_empty` needed a numerical value for me so

```
'hide_empty' =>0
```

worked for me

Comment: it makes no difference if `hide_empty` is set with `false` or `0` : see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1473